# Problem with understanding integration by parts method?

Tags: integration

First of all (before I get started with integration by parts method to solve integrals) I need to know what is the meaning of all terms in integration rules like $a^x,\,e^x,\,\ln\left(x\right),\,$ etc.

I'm having problem with solving integrals using integration by parts method because of integration rules terms meaning, so can any one help me understanding the terms and give me

**Examples**.

I think list below have most of integration rules terms:

- $a$ $\to$ I really need to know.
- $x$ $\to$ I think $x$
- $e^x$ $\to$ I really need to know.
- $a^x$ $\to$ I really need to know.
- $\ln\left(x\right)$ $\to$ I really need to know.

I mean: for the rule $\int a\,\,dx=ax+C$ what is $a$

Please chick this link http://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/integration-rules.html

Comment: You mean $\ln x$; yes?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff yes

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "interation rules terms meaning"?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff for the rule $\int a \,\,dx=ax + C$ what is $a$

Comment: In all your examples the only function that needs integration by parts is the  $\ln$ function.

Comment: When you say "rule"; do you mean "integral"?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Integration Rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a$ is any constant, that does not change when $x$ changes.  For example, $3$ or $-7$.  When they write $\int a dx=ax+C$, that means that $\int 3dx=3x+C$ and $\int (-7)dx=-7x + C$.

$e^x$ is the [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) function, with base $e$.

$a^x$ is the exponential function, with base $a$, where again $a$ is any constant.

$\ln x$ is the (natural) [logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) function.

Comment: Don't we really need $a > 0$ ? Suppose we let $a = -1$, what would the graph $y = a^x$ look like? The standard trick for integrating $a^x$ is to rewrite as $\operatorname{e}^{x\ln a}$. What is $\ln(-1)$?

Comment: @FlybyNight, sure, but if $a\le 0$, then $\ln a$ is undefined, so the integral formula doesn't apply anyways.

Comment: So that needs to be made clear to the OP. S/he is just starting to learn and ought to be made aware of such things.

Comment: Thank you vadim123, now I think I have a basic Informations.